# $ \sum_{n\geq1}(\frac{1}{(n+1)!} ∏_{k=1}^{n} f(k))$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $f: \mathbb N - {0} \to \mathbb N -{0}$  injective function, verify is the serie $ \sum_{n\geq1}(\frac{1}{(n+1)!} ∏_{k=1}^{n} f(k))$ converge or diverge .

I prove for $n=5$ and $n=9$ and found that the series diverge for f injective but how can i prove it in general please help i need yo understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is injective, then it's true that

$$\prod_{k = 1}^n f(k) \ge n!$$

If you can convince yourself of this, you're almost done.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the injective function $f(k) = k$. Take that function, simplify your given series, and you'll quickly get a familiar series.